# CSS menu items not showing in chrome

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

For some reason, this works in firefox and iexplore but not chrome.
It is supposed to hide the submenu until the mouse rolls over it - in chrome the mouseover clearly works as the colour changes etc, but the menu does not pop out!
any help you can offer would be amazing!
thanks!!

```
#menu, #menu ul
{
margin:0px;
 padding:0px;
 list-style:none;
 list-style-position:outside;
 position:relative;
 line-height:2em; /* this would mean the element is double the height of the font */
}

/* set up colours, borders and element padding */
#menu a:link, #menu a:active, #menu a:visited
{
 display:block;
 padding:0px 5px; /* shorthand padding - this means top and bottom padding is 0, left and right are 5px */
 color: #000000; /* link text colour */
 text-decoration:none;
 background-color:#F90; /* specifies background colour of links */
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#FFC;
 /* border stuff */
 border:1px solid #F90; /* shorthand, border is 1px wide, solid and coloured */


}

/* set up hover colour for links */
#menu a:hover
{ 
 background-color:#FC6;
 color:#900;
 border:1px solid #F60;
}

/* position menu elements horizontally */
#menu li
{
 width:7em;
 position:relative;
}

/* position and hide nested lists (width required to make menu display vertically) and "top" value needs same measurement as defined for #menu */
#menu ul
{
 position:absolute;
 width:7em;
 left:7em; /* same value as width - no bigger otherwise gap will appear and menu will not work */
 top:0em; /* line up with parent list item */
 display:none;
}

/* set width of links to 12em */
#menu li ul a
{
 width:7em;
 float:left;
}

/* display information for sub-menus */
#menu ul ul
{
 top:auto;
}

#menu li ul ul
{
 left:7em;
 margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;  /*shorthand margin command */
}

/* display when rolled over - also number of sub-menus to display - if wanted to use more submenus, would need more UL's  (ie ul ul ul instead of ul) */
#menu li:hover ul ul
{
 display:none;
}

#menu li:hover ul, #menu li li:hover ul
{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: try using the direct descendant selector where possible, (`>`), to make things a little clearer. just a thought.

Comment: Can you post a demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), that reproduces this behaviour?

Comment: www.fruitfulcreations.co.uk < that is the live version of the site, sorta embarassed that i only realised the problem with chrome today :P (the "work" part of the menu is the part with the problem, on ff and ie it works, but not in chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lipelip is almost right.

You have to remove `position: relative` from just the *inner* `<li>` tags - **not** the outer ones.

If that's difficult to understand, you could just add this to your CSS instead:

```
#menu li ul li
{
 position:static;
}
```

It fixes the problem by setting the correct `position` property on the inner `<li>` tags only.

Comment: Thankyou!  I have added that and it works perfectly!  Could you explain what I have done wrong so as I can learn from this?  Thanks :)

Comment: This was a while ago, so I'm not certain. I've looked again, and the reason seems to be some weird interaction between having `position: relative` on a parent element, and having `float: left` on `#menu li ul a`. The corollary of this is that you should ensure that only elements which definitely require `position: relative` are given it.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this searching for a solution to a similar problem. OP's site seems to work in Chrome now, but I found that the problem was in the way Chrome handles certain elements. There was a 1px gap between the main menu item and the submenu item, and hitting that gap with the cursor would hide the submenu. The solution was to set margin-top on the submenu to -1px to remove that gap. In OP's case, it appears that gap would have been to the left of the submenu rather than the top.

Note: Mine differs from OP in that I have used `<div>` rather than `<ul>` and `<li>`, but the principle's the same.

site: [WeirdCalculator.com](http://www.weirdcalculator.com)

From CSS stylesheet:

```
.menuitem {
    display: inline;
}

.menuitem:hover .show {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the position:relative; you have on the #menu li {}
Not sure why it's not working in Chrome but I don't think you need it anyway.

Comment: it is needed, it makes sure that the list item is positioned relative to its parent item - if it wasn't there the menu item would appear elsewhere when mouse rolls over - thanks anyway though! :)

Answer (score 0):

Also please check float property for this issue. There is a `float:none` in my CSS, I removed the float and it resolved my issue of text whch was not appearing on popup menus in Chrome.